# sql server 2008 express installation problem in windows xp sp2

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-express, failed-installation, windows-xp-sp2

I need to install Sql Server Express 2008 on my PC which has Windows XP SP2 (32 bit). But while installing Sql Server, the Windows PowerShell installation fails. This ceases the Sql Server installation.

What shall I do now? I found that there's no PowerShell for XP SP2 available , so i need to upgrade to XP SP 3.

Is there any way to install Sql Server 2008 without upgrading to SP3?

Answer (score 1):

If you have Windows XP, you can't download SQL Server 2012 [Express], so to fix, you must install Windows PowerShell.  Then install SQL Server 2008 R2 [Express] again.

http://download.cnet.com/Microsoft-Windows-PowerShell-1-0-for-Windows-XP/3000-2070_4-75450849.html

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlexpress/thread/5a4db558-9f0c-4b44-a90e-ea2f697f0639/) is a discussion on a MS forum about this very issue. There is a post from Mike Wachal about half way down that may very well solve this issue for you.